# if statements with 'str' or 'int'?

Tags: python

My question is relatively simple. Is 'str' easier than 'int' in the following examples?

```
slot_1 = 'med kit'
if slot_1 == 'med kit':
    print('med kit ready')
```

is that faster to run and better than

```
slot_1 = 0
#0 represents med kit
if slot_1 == 0:
    print('med kit ready')
```

Or is the one using integers more pythonic, and runs better?
What if I were to have multiple things, not just med kit. Would it still be better to use strings? If you want any more information I can edit.

Comment: There is no answer to this. You use `==` based on the type of data you are using. I don't see how you have a choice like this in any practical application.

Comment: The general answer to performance questions is: Test it and see for yourself. And what's faster in one situation might be slower in another. But if performance is a big concern, then Python might not be the best choice.

Comment: You are asking what to use as a key?  If so stay with the string, they are easier for a programmer to understand.  And on the VERY off chance they are a performance problem change them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hundreds of answer, depending on too many factors.

But if in doubt, refer to the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

and

> Readability counts.

may suggest to go for

```
slot_1 = 'med kit'
if slot_1 == 'med kit':
    print('med kit ready')
```

since it's more readable

Answer (score 2):

You can look to the Python standard library for a hint of what is most Pythonic.

The [decimal module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/decimal.py) and re module both use named constant strings rather than integer constants.

In Python 3, the [*enum*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum) module provides IntEnum so that you get the intelligibility of readable names and the benefits of ints (can be sequenced and can do math such as bitwise operations).

Comment: The OP could also look into using [`enum`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in speed there is basically no significant difference with one if statement but using strings will accumulate if you have lots of equality tests.  Here is a test on 10,000,000 runs:

```
import time
N = 10000000

# String test
print('String Test')
t0 = time.clock()
slot_1 = 'med kit'
g = 0
for x in range(N):
    if slot_1 == 'med kit':
        g = g + 1
t1 = time.clock()
total = t1-t0     
print("%.8F seconds\n" % total)

# Integer test
print('Integer Test')
t0 = time.clock()
slot_1 = 0
g = 0
for x in range(N):
    if slot_1 == 0:
        g = g + 1
t1 = time.clock()
total = t1-t0 

print("%.8F seconds\n" % total)
```

Output:

```
String Test
0.72845136 seconds

Integer Test
0.69446039 seconds
```

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected a bigger difference between strings and ints. The `timeit` module would give you a better basis to understand whether this difference was significant

Comment: I couldn't remember the best way to time a code snippet which as you pointed out, timeit is best.  I worked around that by just doing a large batch using time.clock() which for longer operations is accurate to less than a microsecond at least on Windows.